# wifi code by c++ convert to android

Tags: android, code-conversion

This is a part of c++ code to connect between client and server, 
I need to an android code corresponds to c++ code?

```
/* Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP */
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
return ("Could not create socket!");

/* Construct the server address structure */
memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));     /* Zero out structure */
echoServAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;             /* Internet address family */
echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);   /* Server IP address */
echoServAddr.sin_port        = htons(echoServPort); /* Server port */

/* Establish the connection to the echo server */
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
return ("Could not connect to socket!");
```

Comment: there's nothing wifi specific there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a code converter (at least not officially) but look into Java's [Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html). See example [here](http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html).

Comment: OK, just I need a code to verify that the socket connection done..

Comment: There are plenty of code samples in the web, just google java socket example.